# Google BigQuery: iterate CONTAINS function over subquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, contains

Lets assume I have two tables:

```
girls       prefixes
------     ----------
Le-na          -na      
Lo-ve          -ve
Li-na          -la
Lu-na          -ta
Len-ka         -ya
```

All girls names and prefixes are different length!

I want to select all girl names that contains prefixes table and to do it in a query(imagine I have many names and many prefixes).

I untested that for single case it is being completed like this:

`SELECT girls,SOME(girls CONTAINS ("-na")) WITHIN RECORD FROM prefixes`

But how do I implement iteration of CONTAINS function over subquery?
e.g.

`SELECT girls,SOME(girls CONTAINS (SELECT * FROM prefixes)) 
 WITHIN RECORD FROM prefixes`
 –– this doesn't work, cause Subselect not allowed in SELECT clause

I'd really appreciate any ideas, I've tried to search for this but couldn't find my case.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried just using `join`?

```
select *
from girls g join
     prefixes p
     on g.girls like concat('%', p.prefix);
```

This should work using standard SQL.

Comment: Thank you very much for suggestion. Here is what google-bigquery response:

`ON clause must be AND of = comparisons of one field name from each table, with all field names prefixed with table name. `

Comment: Make sure to enable [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/), e.g. by putting `#standardSQL` before the query.

Comment: Thank you very much, Sir! Elliott, wish you to have 10/10 day and week!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the prefixes (well, suffixes) are always three characters, you can perform an efficient semi-join with the result of `SUBSTR`:

```
#standardSQL
WITH Girls AS (
  SELECT name
  FROM UNNEST(['Le-na', 'Lo-ve', 'Li-na', 'Lu-na', 'Len-ka']) AS name 
),
Suffixes AS (
  SELECT suffix
  FROM UNNEST(['-na', '-ve', '-la', '-ta', '-ya']) AS suffix
)
SELECT
  name
FROM Girls
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM Suffixes WHERE suffix = SUBSTR(name, LENGTH(name) - 2)
);
```

Or you can use `LIKE`, but it is equivalent to performing a cross join with a filter, so it probably won't be as fast:

```
#standardSQL
WITH Girls AS (
  SELECT name
  FROM UNNEST(['Le-na', 'Lo-ve', 'Li-na', 'Lu-na', 'Len-ka']) AS name 
),
Suffixes AS (
  SELECT suffix
  FROM UNNEST(['-na', '-ve', '-la', '-ta', '-ya']) AS suffix
)
SELECT
  name
FROM Girls
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM Suffixes WHERE name LIKE CONCAT('%', suffix)
);
```

Edit: another option that enumerates all name suffixes for use in the semi-join:

```
#standardSQL
WITH Girls AS (
  SELECT name
  FROM UNNEST(['Le-na', 'Lo-ve-lala', 'Li-na', 'Lu-eya', 'Len-ka']) AS name 
),
Suffixes AS (
  SELECT suffix
  FROM UNNEST(['-na', '-ve', '-lala', '-ta', '-eya']) AS suffix
),
GirlNamePermutations AS (
  SELECT name, SUBSTR(name, LENGTH(name) + 1 - len) AS name_suffix
  FROM Girls
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, (SELECT MAX(LENGTH(suffix)) FROM Suffixes))) AS len
)
SELECT
  name
FROM GirlNamePermutations
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM Suffixes
  WHERE suffix = name_suffix
);
```

If you know the range of suffix lengths, you could hard-code it instead, e.g. replace:

```
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, (SELECT MAX(LENGTH(suffix)) FROM Suffixes))) AS len
```

with:

```
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, 5)) AS len
```

Comment: Sorry, just have an update right now. You assumption is not right, there are different length names and different prefixes length(it can go put to '-nenko') . Thus, using `LIKE CONTACT('%', suffix)` seems very inefficient cause query time jumped over 300 seconds and I was too tired to wait. 

Maybe there are possible CONTAINS iteration in sql?

Answer (score 2):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH girls AS (
  SELECT name
  FROM UNNEST(['Le-na', 'Lo-ve', 'Li-na', 'Lu-na', 'Len-ka']) AS name 
),
suffixes AS (
  SELECT suffix
  FROM UNNEST(['-na', '-ve', '-la', '-ta', '-ya']) AS suffix
)
SELECT name
FROM girls
JOIN suffixes
ON ENDS_WITH(name, suffix)
```

as an option - in case you will need to extend this to find fragments inside name - you can use [`REGEXP_CONTAINS`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#regexp_contains)

```sql
SELECT name
FROM girls
JOIN suffixes
ON REGEXP_CONTAINS(name, suffix)
```

or - [`STARTS_WITH`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#starts_with) to match by prefixes (vs. suffixes)

```sql
SELECT name
FROM girls
JOIN suffixes
ON STARTS_WITH(name, suffix)
```